# Corda Contract within a Contract?

Tags: java, corda, clause

I am trying to build some form of dynamic Corda contract that has a state which can hold a list of independent contracts and independent states for those contracts.

To demystify the concept, think of the 'dynamic Corda contract' as an abstract class which has a `List<SubContract> subcontracts;` where `SubContract` implements `corda.contracts.Contract` as a variable and is instantiated when you invoke the creation of the master contract and you provide a list of possible contracts. (I think it's something similar to the deprecated `Clause` functionality in a previous version of Corda - I don't know why they deprecated it, either)

If I want a transaction to only change the state of a single `SubContract`, I am presuming I would have to collect the states of both:

1. the overall parent/master contract and
2. the other subcontracts alongside the subcontract I am trying to
   modify

as inputs to this transaction?

Is this possible. How do I go about this? (Java SC would be preferred, since I'm not too sure how to translate kt)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By reading round using different terminology, I think I've been able to found some answers that help ease my confusion.

I'll add the links here, and will update if I find anything new.

1. [How does Corda support parent-child relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48277289/11860198)
2. [Corda State Management Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50882846/11860198)

EDIT --- 09/03/2020

Adding these below: contains parent-child states/contract implementation tutorials. The first one is for state persistence in Corda via 'Queryable State'. The second link is the second part to #1 which includes parent-child state relationships.

1. https://medium.com/corda/persisting-corda-states-in-custom-database-tables-using-queryablestate-dedaa18b7050
2. https://medium.com/corda/implementing-hierarchical-relationship-with-corda-queryablestate-15049fed5934